# Add child row as nested datatable within exisiting datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable that lists a number of 'stages' (which relate to work employment procedures being carried out against the individual employee).

I have managed to code this so the table can display child rows. I want each child row to display another datatable which will list associated tasks for the selected stage.

So far I have managed to add and display a child row with the table header. See here:
[Child Row][1]

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover " id="stage_datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th><!-- Detail --></th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Stage</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Desc</th>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Rep Required</th>
            <th>Logged By</th>
            <th>Date Logged</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>                      
</table>
```

The Jquery for my stage table is here:

```
function loadStageTable (action, id) {

$.ajax ( {
    url: './stages/stage_ajax.php',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {action: action, id:id}, // id could be taskID or caseID
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("success");
        iTableCounter = 0;

        var table = $('#stage_datatable').DataTable ( {
            "searching": false,
            "sort": false,
            data:data,
            select: {
                style: 'os'
            },
            responsive: true,
            columns: [
                { 'data': null },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "className":      'details-control',
                    "orderable":      false,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },
                { 'data': 'meeting_id' },
                { 'data': 'stage_desc' },
                { 'data': 'meeting_title' },
                { 'data': 'meeting_desc' },
                { 'data': 'meeting_date_time' },
                { 'data': 'meeting_location' },
                { 'data': 'rep_required' },
                { 'data': 'logged_by' },
                { 'data': 'start_date' }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -11,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>Select</button>"
            }, 
            {
                "targets": -3,
                "className": "dt-body-center",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta){
                    var is_checked = data == true ? "checked" : "";
                    return '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ' + is_checked + ' disabled />';
                   }
            }]
        }); 
        console.log("stage datatable processed");
        $('#stage_datatable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

            var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
            var row = table.row( tr );

            if ( row.child.isShown() ) { // Close this row if already open
                $('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp( function () {
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } );
            }else {
                // table id is required for child rows and will be unique
                iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1
                row.child(getChildRow).show(); // call getChildRow function to obtain the child row html

                var caseID = localStorage.getItem('caseID');
                console.log(caseID);
                loadMyTaskTable('get case tasks', caseID); // this is the AJAX function invoked to retrieve tasks. THIS DOESN'T WORK
                tr.addClass('shown');
                $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown("slow");
            }
        });
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        console.log ("failed");
    }
});
```

In the above I have coded an event that triggers the child row to be inserted:

```
$('#stage_datatable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

            var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
            var row = table.row( tr );

            if ( row.child.isShown() ) { // Close this row if already open
                $('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp( function () {
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } );
            }else {
                // table id is required for child rows and will be unique
                iTableCounter = iTableCounter + 1
                row.child(getChildRow).show(); // call getChildRow function to obtain the child row html

                var caseID = localStorage.getItem('caseID');
                console.log(caseID);
                loadMyTaskTable('get case tasks', caseID); // this is the AJAX function invoked to retrieve tasks
                tr.addClass('shown');
                $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown("slow");
            }
        });
```

The getChildRow is as follows:

```
function getChildRow() {
var x = innerTaskTableTemplate(iTableCounter, taskTableTemplate());
return x;
```

}

The taskTableTemplate parameter is as follows:

```
function taskTableTemplate() {
return '<thead>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<th>Select</th>'+
        '<th>ID</th>'+
        '<th>Task Title</th>'+
        '<th>Desc</th>'+
        '<th>Due Date/Time</th>'+
        '<th>Allocated To</th>'+
        '<th>Logged By</th>'+
        '<th>Date Logged</th>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</thead>'+
    '<tbody></tbody>';
```

}

And the innerTaskTableTemplate function is as follows:

```
function innerTaskTableTemplate(tableID, html) {
var sOut = "<div class='slider'><table id='task_table_" + tableID + "'>";
sOut += html;
sOut += "</table></div>";
console.log(sOut);

return sOut;
```

}

IF I OMIT THIS LINE from my **loadStageTable ** function then the code successfully adds a child row and inserts the table html.

```
loadMyTaskTable('get case tasks', caseID);
```

However, if I include the line then the child row seems to disappear. If I inspect the DOM using firebug I can't find my child row (e.g. 'task_table_1'). See [here][2].

The loadMyTaskTable function is as follows:

```
function loadMyTaskTable (action, id) {

$.ajax ( {
    url: './tasks/task_ajax.php',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {action: action, id:id}, // id could be taskID or caseID
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var taskTable = $('#task_table_1')

        $(taskTable).DataTable ( {
            data:data,
            select: {
                style: 'os'
            },
            responsive: true,
            columns: [
                { 'data': null },
                { 'data': 'task_id' },
                { 'data': 'task_title' },
                { 'data': 'task_desc' },
                { 'data': 'task_due_date' },
                { 'data': 'allocated_to' },
                { 'data': 'logged_by' },
                { 'data': 'start_date' }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -8,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>Select</button>"
            }]
        }); 
        console.log("task table successfully loaded");  
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        console.log ("failed");
    }
});
```

}

Please can you let me know where I am going wrong. i am confident that my AJAX is working fine as I've tried adding the task table html onto the main page and it loads properly this way, but not when I dynamically insert it as a child row in my datatable.

I have tried looking at similar other posts (e.g. [click here][3]) but I think that the code has since been superseded by the datatables new API.

Many thanks.

**Additional Detail**
I have debugged the script and found the following:

1. The script successfully inserts the child row with the task_table_1 html
2. The child row is subsequently removed from the DOM once it hits the *console.log("task table successfully loaded"); * line in my *loadMyTaskTable* function.

Am still not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I only had a superficial regard but maybe this might be helpful: are you conscious that, as soon as you invoke `loadMyTaskTable()`, the rest of `loadStageTable()` is executed _before_ `loadMyTaskTable()` really does its job?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - appreciated. But the code beneath the loadMyTaskTable function just adds the red close image and applies animation to the div that the table resides in. And it's all part of the event function so I don't think that is the problem - but I may well be wrong. Any further insight you can offer is very much appreciated as I've spent ages searching for a solution with no joy.

Comment: Ok. So did you try debugging? You should first put a breakpoint just before  the `loadMyTaskTable()` (to control the presence of your ghost row :), then another just after (to enforce that it is not dropped further). From there, placing another breakpoint somewhere inside `loadMyTaskTable()`, look if the row already disappeared, move the breakpoint up if yes, down if no, and so on...

Comment: Thank you. I will try that tomorrow. Appreciated

Comment: Feel free to come again if it didn't be sufficient to fix.

Comment: Thank you cFreed. Really appreciate it. Have tried debugging and have updated my log above. Essentially, the child row is inserted and subsequently removed from the DOM once it hits the console.log("task table successfully loaded"); * line in my loadMyTaskTable function. Are you able to suggest anything else?

Comment: Hmm... sounds weird. Do you mean exactly that the row exists yet _just before_ the `console.log()` statement executes, and disappears just after that? I'd more likely suspect this to happen inside `$(taskTable).DataTable()`. Can you precisely confirm/infirm?

Comment: Happy new year cFreed. When I debug it in Firebug, I can see that the new child row is inserted into the DOM when the row.child(getChildRow).show() line of code runs. If I look at the HTML tab in Firebug i can see that task_table_1 now exists although in the browser I can only see that a row has been added - the table does not appear.  The child row (and task_table_1 element) disappears from the HTML once the AJAX command is completed in the loadMyTaskTable function - i.e. when it reaches the console.log("task table successfully loaded") function.

Comment: I should point out that if I simply comment out the loadMyTaskTable function (and therefore do NOT attempt to apply the datatable plugin to my task_table_1) then I actually can see the physical table header appear in the browser when I debug the script. Does that make sense? Again, many thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry, off this week. But I'll get a try ASAP.

Comment: Thank you very much cFreed.

Comment: Here again, and I could look at your issue. Without knowing the contents of what you get through the Ajax requests I've some trouble to really distinguish how it works. Currently I can see only one point I guess it could turn wrong: in the Ajax request in `loadMyTaskTable()` you populate `#task_table_1`, while it seems to be also the (dynamically created) id of the container where you previously created "the" child row in `innerTaskTableTemplate()`, so it could be overwritten there. If this remark doesn't help, could you edit your question to show the exact content of your 2 Ajax requests?

Comment: Hi cFreed. Thank you. I will check tomorrow. I also learnt recently about Jquery When function so will do some testing tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I am having this exact same issue and it's driving me crazy.  Everything loads in the table just fine except when I try to initialize datatables plugin on the table within the child row.  If I do that, the whole thing just vanishes.

It's also worth noting, that to ensure everything within the ajax call is working correctly, if I try to load the ajax data within a div OUTSIDE of the first datatable, everything works fine. Even when I initialize the new table with the datatable plugin. 

The problem seems to only happen if you try to init a new datatable within the child row.

Comment: Hi Jason. I ended up abandoning this as the project got shelved for various reasons. However, I suspect the problem can be resolved by using Deferreds to ensure the nested table only loads once the parent table has finished fully loading. Have you got an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726346/add-nested-datatable-within-child-row-of-another-datatable

Comment: I managed to figure a bit more out. So there's a td in the parent tr that populates the child info. Up until now, i've always left that td blank seeing as I was going to use an AJAX call to populate it's contents.  Well, if I hardcode an empty table with the same ID as the one in the ajax call, the table within the td inside of the parent tr gets datatables initialized. But the child table stays inactive... or rather not initialized.